# grep all lines that have at least X words in them

Tags: bash

I have a script named a.sh that produces an output - some lines of text.

I have another script named b.sh and I'd like to take the output of a.sh and hold it in a variable.

or even better to pipe it immidiately and remove all lines that are too short - meaning all lines that have less than X amount of words.
each word is seperated by a space(or multiple spaces)

how can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps something like `grep '\(.\{9,\}\).*\1'` will work (9 or more words) ?

Comment: @DarkLeader : Define what is a **word**. For instance, how many words are in the line `abc_def'xyz  風呂場`?

Comment: @user1934428 I would consider it as two words. according to the assignment I was given a seperator is a space " "

Comment: @DarkLeader : This is perhaps the most important information for your question, so you should put it into your question and not in a commen! Therefore, `X\tY` (where \t is meant to be a tab character) should also be a single word?

Comment: @user1934428 no, i think they are two words. I don't think the assignment was that specific for tabs - there are test cases and I didn't see any tabs so I ignored it.

Comment: @DarkLeader I think these points are important, because for instance the `awk` solutions posted here, assume that the fields are separated by spaces, not tabs. The `wc` solutions proposed OTOH assumes characters in addition to spaces, so they would give different results for my examples (by treating strings as several words, which, according your definition, should be a single word). Unless you precisely define what you want to achieve, you can't expect honestly accept one of the answers provided.

Comment: @user1934428 I see. well for now I got the answer I was looking for. but for the future I'll make sure to be more specific about input and output. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pipe the script awk and let it count words: `awk '{ if (NF>4) { print }}'`

Awk's default field separator separates the line into words. This means that `if` the number of fields (`NF`) is more than (`>`) `4` awk will `print`s the line.

It can be shortened to `awk 'NF>4'` since awk's default action is to print.

An alternative approach would be to use `wc` (since it literally stands for word count). You could use it in the b script like this:

```sh
while read line; do
  if [[ $(wc -w <<< "$line") -gt 4 ]]
    then
    echo $line
  fi
done
```

Comment: how can I hold the output of my other script in a variable in order to iterate over it?

Comment: No need to hold it. Redirect the output of a.sh to the while loop.

Comment: this is a new subject for me, if you don't mind please add a line that redirects the output of a.sh to this while loop

Comment: if you put it in `b.sh` you could go `./a.sh | ./b.sh`. If you put your output in a variable you can go `echo $var | while read...`

Comment: I see thanks! last question, how can I hold the output of a.sh into $var ?

Comment: `var=$(./a.sh)`. or see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score -1):

inside b.sh:

```
./a.sh "$1" "$2" "$3" | awk -v COUNT=$4 'NF>=COUNT'
```

I still haven't been able to hold the output in a variable but this worked for the parsing

Comment: To hold it in a variable in `b.sh` just go: `var=$(./a.sh ""$1" "$2" "$3" | awk "NF>=$COUNT")`

Comment: As far I see,  the awk-solution would consider the line `foo,bar` as having a single word (NF==1), and the line `foo    ,    bar` as having 3 words (NF==3). Words and awk-Fields are different things.